# Me devuelve los datos con el echo, pero no llegan a mi base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
                    
    <div id="documento">
                      <h1>&bull;Documento&bull;</h1>
                      
                      <div id="documento">
                  <h1>&bull;Documento&bull;</h1>
                  <img id="x" src="imagenes/cruzar.png">
                  <div class="underline">
                  </div>
                  <form action="#" method="post" id="contact_form">
                    <div class="name">
                    <label for="name"></label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre del grupo" name="name" id="name_input" required>
                  </div>
                 <div class="message">
                   <label for="message"></label>
                    <textarea name="content" placeholder="Escribe tu opinión aca" id="message_input" cols="30" rows="5" required></textarea>
                    <textarea name="content2" placeholder="Escribe tu opinión aca" id="message2_input" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
                  </div>
                  <div class="submit">
                    <input type="submit" name="register" value="Enviar documento" id="register" />
                  </div>
                </form>
                
              </div>
                      
                    </form>
                    <?php
             
                   include('../../registrar.php');
    
                   ?>
                    
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

con_db.php

```
<?php
    
    
    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","isla2");

?>
```

registrar.php

```
<?php

include('con_db.php');



    if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
        
            $name = trim($_POST['name']);
            $content = $_POST['content'];
            $date = date("y/m/d");
            $content2 = $_POST['content2'];
            
            
            $consulta = "INSERT INTO `users`(`nombre`, `texto`, `texto2`, `fecha`) VALUES ('$name','$content','$content2','$date')";
            echo $consulta;
            $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);        
    
    }
```

Los datos me los devuelve perfectamente con el `echo $consulta`, pero no sé por qué no se envían a la base de datos, adjunto el código que estoy usando, desde ya gracias por la ayuda, probablemente no estoy viendo algo muy básico y pido disculpas si es una boludez, pero enserio que no tengo idea de lo que sucede.

Comment: Intenta añadir **NULL** como parámetro para tu ID, me imagino que este es autoincrementada, algo como: ```VALUES (NULL, '$name','$content','$content2','$date')```

Answer (score 0):

En lo particular lo haría de la siguiente manera

```
<?php

    include('con_db.php');

        if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
                $name = trim($_POST['name']);
                $content = $_POST['content'];
                $date = date("y/m/d");
                $content2 = $_POST['content2'];

                $consulta = "INSERT INTO users (nombre, texto, texto2, fecha) VALUES ('$name', '$content', '$content2', '$date')";
                    echo $consulta;

                    if (mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta)){
                      echo "Registro exitoso";
                    } else {
                      echo "Error: " . $consulta . "" . mysqli_error($conexion);
                    }
        }
?>
```

Pero tengo curiosidad también, tu variable `$date` noté que en ningún lado se pedía en tu HTML, por lo que considero que podría ser que lo insertes con alguna de las siguientes opciones (la que más te convenga):

1. CURRENT_DATE : retorna la fecha actual con formato "YYYY-MM-DD" o "YYYYMMDD"
2. CURRENT_TIME :retorna la hora actual con formato "HH:MM:SS" o "HHMMSS"
3. CURDATE() : retorna la fecha actual con formato "YYYY-MM-DD" o "YYYYMMDD"
4. NOW() : retorna la fecha y hora actual.
5. SYSDATE() : retorna la fecha y hora actual.

De ser así modificaría tu *$consulta* de la siguiente forma:

```
$consulta = "INSERT INTO users (nombre, texto, texto2, fecha) VALUES ('$name', '$content', '$content2', CURRENT_DATE)";
```

Y quitaría el `$date = date("y/m/d");` dentro de tu `if (isset($_POST['register'])){...}`.